# Chain error and Verifying certificate

Tags: .net, web-services, certificate, keychain, pkcs#7

I got a problem with [PKCS #7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS) that's driving me nuts. Here's is the thing:

1. I have an [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) webservice that makes requests to another third-party server and receives a PKCS #7 signed token in response (it's actually not important where this token comes from). My web service then checks the token's signature (and validity) and returns the enclosed data to the user that invoked the method.
2. The web service is configured to run in a dedicated application pool, which runs under a Windows [AD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) user account, [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) 6.
3. To perform the verification, I do this (signature has the token):

   ```
   public static byte[] VerifyAndExtractEnvelopedData(byte[] signature)
   {
       if (signature == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("signature");

       // Decode the signature
       SignedCms cms = new SignedCms();
       cms.Decode(signature);
       cms.CheckSignature(false);

       if (cms.Detached)
           throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot extract enveloped content from a detached signature.");

       return cms.ContentInfo.Content;
   }
   ```
4. I deployed the web service (IIS 6). When I try to run the afore mentioned webmethod, upon the signature verification, I get the error:

   > A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority

In order to simplify things, I wrote a little Windows Forms application with the exact same code. I logged in interactively to the same server where the web service is hosted, using the same user account in the application pool's. Run the EXE file there and it works fine, that is,  were able to verify the signature perfectly. IMO, this rules out any problem like a missing  [certificate authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) (CA) certificate and so on (in fact, I have the signer's .CER file, I open it in Windows, and it tells me that the chain is OK).

So apparently the only difference is that in the first case my process is a web service and in the second a desktop EXE file. What else could be happening that prevents me to perform the verification in the first case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could be hitting different trust stores on the relying party, see *[Certificate stores](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_cmuncertstor.mspx?mfr=true)*.

Also, check out the involved certificates with PKIF, PITT, Portecle or similar tools for validity, proper OIDs, chaining, etc.